# Logs not showing in xcode when running on device

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to run my app on device connected with Xcode....I dont see NSLog output in console.

When I run on simulator, I do see NSLog output on console

What could be the issue?

Comment: do your breakpoints get stopped? do you have a developer provisioning set?

Comment: yes to both questions

Comment: do you use external logger or standard NSLog?

Comment: It should get displayed on both, until one manages NSLog with some preprocessor macro management

Answer (score 0):

As a generic answer to that question it could be:

1. Provisioning profile set (whether it is development or any other)
2. what kind of logger is in use if other than NSLog I would check default [log level](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/LoggingErrorsAndWarnings.html) if it is lower than `Error` it won't show in the console
3. Some pragma changing NSLog into NOP on a device

Comment: link to the apple docs is dead